# How to use Flask app config while the app is being created (using an app factory)?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Suppose I have something like this in `app/models.py`:

```py
from flask import current_app as app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

db = SQLAlchemy()

class LoginLink(db.Model):
    ...
    expiration_date = db.Column(
        db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False,
        server_default=func.now() + str(app.config["LOGIN_LINK_EXP_TIME"])  # Error here!!!
    )
```

And this in `app/__init__.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import CONFIG_OBJECT

def create_app(config_name):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(CONFIG_OBJECT[config_name])

    from app.models import db
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all(app=app)

    return app
```

Finally, this is my `config.py`:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

CONFIG_OBJECT = {
    "dev": "config.DevConfig",
    "prod": "config.ProdConfig"
}

class Config:
    ...

class DevConfig(Config):
    LOGIN_LINK_EXP_TIME = timedelta(seconds=30)

class ProdConfig(Config):
    LOGIN_LINK_EXP_TIME = timedelta(minutes=30)
```

I tried to use `app.app_context()` everywhere (believe me) and I'm still getting this error:

`RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

I'm just trying to do the following: in a development environment I want the login links to expire in 30 seconds (for testing and demonstration purposes), but login links will last 30 minutes in a production environment.

How to accomplish this **using different config environments**?

**Note:** this is intended to be a generic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had a misconception about application factories. We have the following from the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/appfactories/):

> The downside is that you cannot use the application object in the blueprints at import time. **You can however use it from within a request.**

Additionally:

> It’s preferable to create your extensions and app factories **so that the extension object does not initially get bound to the application.**

What is in bold is what I was doing wrong: using the application object outside a request and bounding the extension to the application.

Therefore, I only see two solutions:

1. Use the `app.config` object (or dict) only within requests (the best IMHO).
2. Don't include configs that require to be used outside of requests in the `app.config` object (although this may complicate testing a bit).